# Get some sort of notification on certain events in public channel

Tags: telegram

I'm on a telegram group of which I'm not admin. In that particular channel, there are lots of messages and "useless" information. I want to make something so when someone in the group says a particular word, I'll get a notification (maybe a private msg?). I've searched but other answers mention the bot API, but, as far as I have found, bots can't be added to groups without being admin, not even with the invitation link. How can I access the messages of the group to process them?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, bots can't get message in channel without administrator permission, and they can't join group by themselves.

If you want to get all messages in group, please **disable** privacy mode via `/setprivacy` in [@BotFather](https://t.me/BotFather), and re-invite to group.